How to get ACS ACR1222L to recognise RFID tag
The ACS ACR1222L works fine on my windows 10 pc.  I plug it in, bring up nfc tools for desktop and when I place an RFID sticker on it, it beeps and displays the contents of the tag.
I tried moving this setup to a raspberry pi 5. The OS is as follows:
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"

First I installed the drivers.  I then read the read.me and it said to install pcsc-lite (wrong way around).


Before installing the driver, unplug the reader first and make sure that you have installed pcsc-lite package for your Linux distribution.


I then tried to install the pcsc-lite package:
sudo apt install pcsc-lite

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pcsc-lite

I've been reading around different forums, e.g. github which suggested
sudo apt install libpcsclite-dev 

That library actually installed but pcsc-lite is still not installed:
dpkg -l | grep pcsc
ii  libpcsc-perl                         1.4.14-5+b3                         arm64        Perl interface to the PC/SC smart card library
ii  libpcsclite-dev:arm64                1.9.9-2                             arm64        Middleware to access a smart card using PC/SC (development files)
ii  libpcsclite1:arm64                   1.9.9-2                             arm64        Middleware to access a smart card using PC/SC (library)
ii  pcsc-tools                           1.6.2-1                             arm64        Some tools to use with smart cards and PC/SC
ii  pcscd                                1.9.9-2                             arm64        Middleware to access a smart card using PC/SC (daemon side)

The libraries are installed by not pcsc-lite
When I try pcsc_scan, I get the following
pcsc_scan
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.6.2 (c) 2001-2022, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: Virtual PCD 00 00
1: Virtual PCD 00 01
2: ACS ACR1222 3S PICC Reader 00 00
 
Tue Jun 18 11:48:49 2024
 Reader 0: Virtual PCD 00 00
  Event number: 0
  Card state: Card removed, 
 Reader 1: Virtual PCD 00 01
  Event number: 0
  Card state: Card removed, 
 Reader 2: ACS ACR1222 3S PICC Reader 00 00
  Event number: 0
  Card state: 

It's appearing in slot 2 but no matter what I do that reader is not recognising the tag.  When I check nfc-list, I get the following:
sudo nfc-list
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: acr122_pcsc:ACS ACR1222 3S PICC Reader 00 00

Any ideas?

Here is a thread about the error message https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/issues/576
